# Reducing Multiple Variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can I reduce **multiple** **variables** in JavaScript?
For example if I have 3 variables:

```
     var foo = 10;
     var boo = 15;
     var lol = 15;

     //Normal syntax:
     foo -=1; // -> foo will be 9
     boo -=1; // -> boo will be 14
     lol -=1; // -> lol will be 14
```

Is there an option to do it with one line? or better syntax?
For example: `foo ,boo ,lol -=1;`

Comment: no, you can't. Only each variable, like in upper example

Comment: `foo--; boo--; lol--;` is the shortest way I can think of, but obviously that isn't the same as typing the operator once and having it apply to all variables. I'm curious: is there another language that you use where there *is* a way to do it all with a single operator?

Comment: And avoid this kind of things ! humans needs to read code well written without any hidden subtilities ! if you want / need just use minifier/uglifier/...

Comment: `console.log(--foo, --boo, --lol);` you can write one line through console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. Standard JavaScript does not give this opportunity. The worse thing that you nearly cannot do it functionally as well. `lol -=1;` or `lol--;` is just a shortcut for `lol = lol - 1;`. So if you will try to write a function, which does that for you e.g.:

```
function reduce() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arguments[i] = arguments[i] - 1;
  }
}
```

and then call it like

```
reduce(foo, bar, lol);
```

it just won't work because you pass primitive numbers (not references). Every time you change the number inside of the function it won't change the number itself but it will return a new number instead.

This could be solved by using some object to store all the variables, e.g.:

```
var vars = {
  foo: 12,
  bar: 13,
  lol: 14
};

function reduce(variables) {
  for (variable in variables) {
    if (variables.hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
      variables[variable] -= 1;
    }
  }

  return variables;
}

reduce(vars);
```

But this is not a list of 3 variables, this is kind of a context you attach them to.

If you do the stuff in a global scope (e.g. in a window without wrapping the stuff in a function), you can combine both ways above into one (`Window` stores all var-declared variables inside):

```
function reduce(vars) {
  var varslist = vars.split(',');

  for (var i = 0; i < varslist.length; i++) {
    window[varslist[i]] -= 1;
  }
}

reduce('foo,boo,lol');
```

but as soon as you move it to some subcontext it won't work any longer. Also it looks very nasty. I would rather prefer the second solution with `vars` object representing your variables context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one line, but you still have to repeat the operation:

```
foo--, bar--, lol--;
```

Read about the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It can be useful, but it's usually not very readable.

I wouldn't even combine `var` statements into 1:

```
var foo = 1, bar = 2, lol = 3;
```

because if a var changes, the entire line changes.

I used to do this:

```
var foo = 1,
    bar = 2,
    lol = 3;
```

but that's bad practice too, because deleting `foo` or `lol` will change more than just 1 line (because the `var` prefix or `;` suffix).

Sometimes verbosity is good:

```
var foo = 10;
var boo = 15;
var lol = 15;

foo -= 1;
boo -= 1;
lol -= 1;
```